# Split a string within a pandas DataFrame element and recombine a section of the list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to split a string within a pandas element, then recombine a section of the split string. I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_NN','PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_NN','PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_NN',
                            'PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_ER','PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_ER','PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_ER']})

df['domain'] = df['code'].str.split("_")
```

This code works for splitting the string on the underscore. Now I would like to take the resulting split list within the column and recombine the first three elements such that:

**PC001-S001_D_CFI4-1_NN** ==> **PC001-S001_D_CFI4-1**

I can do this if I was just applying to a string using:

```
a = 'PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_NN'
b = a.split("_")[0:3]
c = "_".join(b)
```

However, I have tried to apply this to pandas without much success.

Any advice would be greatly received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [Series.str.rsplit(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html):

```
In [11]: df['domain'] = df['code'].str.rsplit('_',1).str[0]

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
                     code               domain
0  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_NN  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
1  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_NN  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
2  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_NN  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
3  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_ER  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
4  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_ER  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
5  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_ER  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
```

or just remove the last section:

```
In [7]: df['domain'] = df['code'].str.replace(r'\_\w+?$','')

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
                     code               domain
0  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_NN  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
1  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_NN  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
2  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_NN  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
3  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_ER  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
4  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_ER  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
5  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_ER  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `str[:3]` for select first 3 `list`s and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['domain'] = df['code'].str.split("_").str[:3].str.join('_')
print (df)

                     code               domain
0  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_NN  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
1  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_NN  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
2  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_NN  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
3  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_ER  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
4  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_ER  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
5  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1_ER  PC001-S002_D_CFI4-1
```