# Split list in rows python pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I have lists of unknown columns in python  and I want to split it into rows.How I can do this.

```
numberArray1                  |  numberArray10                    |numberArray11 | . . .
[32.09561, 32.43092, 32.37599]| [37.015972, 37.015972, 36.889534] | [996.2953, 996.2609, 996.28845]|. . . . to N columns
```

This all data stores in cells of dataframe

Need to convert the horizontal value in my rows to vertical values corresponding to the respective columns.

Expected output would be.

```
numberArray1  numberArray10  numberArray11                    
32.09561      37.015972      996.2953
32.43092      37.015972      996.2609
32.37599      36.889534      996.28845
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string within a pandas DataFrame element and recombine a section of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48149189/split-a-string-within-a-pandas-dataframe-element-and-recombine-a-section-of-the)

Comment: Read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to understand how to ask a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pandas,

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("your_csv.csv")
new_df=pd.DataFrame()
for col in df.columns:
   new_df[col]=pd.DataFrame({col:pd.Series(df[col][0].str[1:-1].split(','))})
```

`new_df` is your expected dataframe

Comment: Thanks for your response ..but I have unlimited number of columns..I mean I need to add loop

Comment: you have everything in a column? , is it possible to attach a photo of how your data looks like/

Comment: yeah, you can loop through your columns, you attach a sample photo. I will modify the code

Comment: I have data in csv file with same format having 30 plus columns and each column contains a list

Comment: I have data in csv ...I can share it with other source if you want

Comment: you can take a screenshot and upload it in your question edit

Comment: It looks like this

Comment: Only one row in your data ?

Comment: I will edit the answer in 1 hour ok? I am outside now

Comment: thanks for help...but when I run code it shows error like 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Use ,`new_df[col]=pd.DataFrame({col:pd.Series(df[col][0].str[1:-1].split(','))})` and see